# How to execute a command line in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, command-line, jailbreak

I would like to execute a command line in iPhone iOS with Xcode objective C project, I used `system()` function but it won't work!

I installed `ssh` on my jailbreak iPhone and checked that application, 
and I write this code in the application which I making

```
system('id > /tmp/id');
```

After installing and executing the software there is no file in `/tmp/id`.

How I can fix this? There isn't any problem if help me in Swift too, I just want to execute a command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/):

> Using the NSTask class, your program can run another program as a subprocess and can monitor that program’s execution.

Something like this:

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
task.arguments = ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I used this code and "import Foundation" in first line of code, but it still giving me error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'NSTask'`, do i missing something ? I think it's just working for mac os x, not the ios

Comment: You're right, [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/) is only available for Mac OS. You won't be able to execute anything from the command line on iOS without jailbreaking.

Comment: my phone is jailbreaked , how can I execute command line ? I used `system()`  and `execv()` in object-c but still doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine using the system function, but there are a few gotchas:

1) If its an Xcode project, it will be sandboxed even in a jailbroken iPhone, so your app will not be able to write in "/tmp". Use the app's writable path instead.

2) In any case, when calling system() you should use the absolute path of your executable, e.g. :

```
system('/usr/bin/id > /tmp/id');
```

Comment: thanks, can use tell me please what is app's writable path ?

Comment: how I can turn off sandbox, and use `system('/usr/bin/id > /tmp/id')` ? I seen iphone have ssh software , how is that work ?